Does kfp.dsl.Condition allow for multiple conditions?
I'm currently working on a Vertex AI Pipeline using kfp.
Right now I have a pipeline parameter called is_enabled that submits a model automatically to the model registry if it is enabled.
I want to include it in my current pipeline, so I have this condition:
        with dsl.Condition(
            ((model_registry_lookup.outputs["found_model"] == False) or (is_enabled)),  # noqa
            name="no_model_found_in_registry",
        ):

However, it looks like it only evaluates the first expression (model_registry_lookup.outputs["found_model"] == False) and ignores the boolean pipeline parameter is_enabled.
Is this a limitation of Kubeflow Pipelines? What would be a workaround?
I tried switching the code above
        with dsl.Condition(
            ((is_enabled) or (model_registry_lookup.outputs["found_model"] == False)),  # noqa
            name="no_model_found_in_registry",
        ):

And now it only evaluates is_enabled. Which leads me to assume it only evaluates the first expression. Is it correct?
